# Can your iphone be unwittingly jailbroken?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible for an iphone to be jailbroken by visiting a malicious website in your iphone's browser?

Comment: This might be better answered on a mobile forum.

Comment: I want to know answers from a security perspective.

Comment: What security perspective? This is purely an iPhone-specific technical question. It requires knowledge of the jailbreaking process, with the potential answers of 'yes' or 'no', which are explained with technical details of the specific device type. This is a product-specific technical question.

Comment: I know that you use to be able to jailbreak them in the past just by visiting a website due to vunerabilities in the browser.  The site was called jailbreakme.com (and still exists) but you have to have specific versions of iOS.   Apple has patched a lot of the vulnerabilities and it could still be possible, but I don't know of any recent browser-based jailbreaks.

Comment: It depends on if the iPhone browser has any existing buffer overflow bugs then. If yes, then probably yes.

Comment: As per the basic principles of the site the question deals with: a) "Specific issues regarding the protection of assets from threats and vulnerabilities"; and b) "Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered".

Answer (score 2):

Jailbreaking from the browser used to be possible. Older iPhone OS's will still have this potential vulnerability. That being said, jailbreaking via a browser has now been outdated and patched by Apple. I believe it was patched in iOS 5.0 and has been patched since. So older iPhone users (pre-iOS 5.0; which are few and far between) might still be vulnerable and potentially a malicious website could exploit this. As of now, all jailbreaks (to the best of my knowledge) require a physical attachment to a computer in order to load on the jailbroken firmware.

That all being said, I will be one of the first to say that jailbreaking a device does not make it unsecure. It becomes unsecure when you jailbreak and install potentially harmful apps only available with a jailbreak or apps which create extra security holes. However, there is the concern that if a jailbreak can be installed via an iPhone browser, a modified firmware with security holes and viruses could be installed to. Again, though, I wouldn't concern myself over it as long as you're running a semi-new iOS firmware.